# I started working in ocaml and i can't figure out a small thing about nat types

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I am trying to write a function of type nat -> nat -> nat -> nat
which i named sudan_nat it works on the principle of sudan function
**

```
Wikipedia:
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudan_function
```

```
//This is the type definition
type nat = Zero | Succ of nat

let add_nat m n =
  let rec helper m = match m with Zero -> n | Succ m -> Succ (helper m)
  in helper m

let zero_nat = Zero
let one_nat  = Succ zero_nat             
let two_nat  = Succ one_nat             
let four_nat  = add_nat two_nat two_nat`



let sudan_nat m n p = 
  let rec helper m n = match m with Zero -> n | Succ m -> Succ (helper m n)
  in helper (add_nat (add_nat m n) p) one_nat
```

This is the code i wrote for the sudan_nat

My case for testing output is
((sudan_nat one_nat two_nat two_nat) = (add_nat (add_nat four_nat four_nat) four_nat))

```
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))))
```

This is the result for left side

```
Succ
 (Succ
   (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))))))))))
```

This is the result of right side i have been scratching my head for hours now any kind of suggestion is welcomed thank you

Comment: For debugging purposes I'd suggest writing a function nat -> int to convert nat to integers, and conversely int -> nat

Answer (score 2):

`four_nat` is `Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero)))`. That's 4 `Succ` constructors. You've added 3 of these together, so you have... 12. 4 times 3 = 12.

When it comes to evaluating `sudan_nat nat_one nat_two nat_two` it breaks down:

```
sudan_nat nat_one nat_two nat_two
helper (add_nat (add_nat nat_one nat_two) nat_two) one_nat
helper (add_nat (add_nat Zero nat_two) nat_two) one_nat
helper (add_nat nat_two nat_two) one_nat
helper nat_four one_nat
...
Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))
```

As an additional style suggestion, you may wish to define a module to organize your code.

```
module Nat =
struct
  type t = Zero | Succ of t
  
  let add m n =
    let rec helper m = 
      match m with 
      | Zero -> n 
      | Succ m -> Succ (helper m)
    in 
    helper m

  let one = Succ Zero
  let two = Succ (Succ Zero)
  let four = add two two
  
  let sudan m n p = 
    let rec helper m n = 
      match m with 
      | Zero -> n 
      | Succ m -> Succ (helper m n)
    in 
    helper (add (add m n) p) one
end
```

Comment: so what is the problem with my solution i can see the dry running how can i generate it 12 times

Comment: `let eight_nat = add_nat four_nat four_nat in sudan_nat eight_nat two_nat one_nat`?

Comment: what's this? can you elaborate i am not getting it p.s thanks for code style